# How to get inserted data after INSERT …. IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a scala code to work with cassandra with a datastax driver. I want to use `INSERT …. IF NOT EXISTS` instead `SELECT and INSERT`. I can’t find the right way to get `INSERTED INFORMATION` after `INSERT`, the session.execute returns me only `FALSE or TRUE`. Could you help me write a code which lets me get data if a row with such a key is inserted ?

Connect code:

```
  private val query=
    s"INSERT INTO ${keyspace}.${table} (code,date) VALUES (?, ?) IF NOT EXISTS"

  override def insertIfNotExist(code: String, date: String): Boolean = {
    connector.withSessionDo { session =>
      val prep = connector.prepare(session, query)
      val res: Boolean = session.execute(prep.bind(code, date) // return only boolean

      ).wasApplied()
    }
  }


insert into date_table(code, date) VALUES ('5', '2028-01-01') if not exists;
```

if row is in table the response in console is:

```
[applied]| code| date
false,5,2021-11-15
```

and I want to acces in Scala code to 5,2021-11-15

```
if not only
[applied]
true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the call to `session.execute` always returns `ResultSet`, it's only `wasApplied` returns boolean.  If you want to get more details, you can change it to:

```scala
val res: Boolean = session.execute(prep.bind(code, date))
if (res.wasApplied) {
  // handle applied case - in this case you get only the boolean value
} else {
  // handle not-applied - in this case you can extract information
  // about conflicting values
}
```

Comment: thank you for response